# How can I return unique rows when using an INNER JOIN in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: links, keywords, and keywords_links. A link can have multiple keywords, and multiple links can have the same keyword. `keywords_links` is used to join `links` and `keywords`.
When I run the following query, multiple rows of the same link is returned because multiple keywords match. How can I modify this query to return unique rows?

```
SELECT links . * 
FROM  `links` 
INNER JOIN keywords_links ON keywords_links.link_id = id
INNER JOIN keywords ON keywords.id = keywords_links.keyword_id
WHERE keywords.keyword
IN (
'php', 'sql', 'html', 'css'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to put a `DISTINCT` after the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT links.*
...
...
```

But perhaps a more efficient solution would be to rewrite your query so that it doesn't have to make the distinction across EVERY column:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM links a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.link_id
    FROM keywords_links a
    INNER JOIN keywords b ON
        a.keyword_id = b.id AND
        b.keyword IN ('php', 'sql', 'html', 'css')
    GROUP BY a.link_id
) b ON a.id = b.link_id
```

Comment: I've never tried this with inner joins but I see no reason why it won't work. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) is some additional documentation on how the `DISTINCT` function works.